# Select elements based on class and element type

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I select all elements within an HTML document with a specific class and specific element type?

I'm trying to select all anchors with the class `title loggedin` from an HTML document (and then open them within the browser). These are within parragraphs with the class `title`.

They are leafs in the following DOM tree:

```
+ body
  + div class='content'
    + div id='siteTable' class='sitetable linklisting'
      + div class='thing id-t3_xxxx xxx xxx link'
        + div class='entry unvoted'
            + p class='title'
              + a class='title loggedin '
```

Where `x` indicates variable content.

(I'm looking to do this in raw JavaScript, ie, not in jQuery.)

Comment: what is the type of element/tag with class `title loggedin`?

Comment: @sarfaz Anchor, ie, `a`.

Comment: In modern browsers: `document.querySelectorAll('a.title.loggedin')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var aElems = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<aElems.length; ++i) {
    var classesArr = aElems[i].className.split(/\s+/),
        classesObj = {};
    for (var j=0; j<classesArr.length; ++j) {
        classesObj[classesArr[i]] = true;
    }
    if (classesObj.hasOwnProperty("title") && classesObj.hasOwnProperty("loggedin")) {
        // action
    }
}
```

Some explanation:

- `document.getElementsByTagName` returns an array of elements of the given type (in this case `a`)
- for every element in that array the array class names is extracted (see `aElems[i].className.split`)
- every class name is then used as property name for an index object
- the index is then looked up for the two class names (see `aElems[i].className.split`)

Comment: It seems you're relying on `Array.prototype.indexOf` which isn't supported in all browsers...

Comment: @J-P: Good argument. I changed it so it doesn’t require that method.

Comment: I ultimately went for a more simple solution to that posted. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Technically that's not one class, it's two classes: `title` and `loggedin`. You can use [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) for that.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("title loggedin");
```

You can pass two classes to that method.

Comment: It's worth noting that `getElementsByClassName()` has compatibility implications (at this point in time): http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements

Comment: The compatibility implications are ancient problems and no longer relative by todays standards.

Answer (score 3):

Fetching all elements of a certain tag type using `document.getElementsByTagName()` and walking through the list should work. With multiple classes you'd have to parse the `className` property (which will contain the full string `title loggedin`) manually.

I assume you have good reason to do this in pure JavaScript; it would be much more convenient using a framework like jQuery or Prototype.

Comment: Naturally, it'd be easier in jQuery, but I'd prefer to know how to walk before I run! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but if you ever wanted to know how jQuery selects elements you can view the source of their standalone selector engine [Sizzle.js](http://sizzlejs.com/) which over the years has been developed by a lot of smart people who have spent a great deal of time on performance :)